# how to delete two lines that starts with same character in sed?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a text file. In case there are more than one consecutive line that starts with @, I want to delete all these lines, except of the last occurrence of of a line with @.

For example, lets say I have input file:

> abc
>
> @abc
>
> @def
>
> 333
>
> @asd
>
> @poi
>
> @789

The output should be:

> abc
>
> @def
>
> 333
>
> @789

Comment: I dont think you can do that with **sed**, as it works on each line of input separately

Comment: @poncha use it with tr -- see my answer below. I just found out about tr, but it's been surprisingly useful.

Comment: @Kasapo thanks for the tip... but then you need to replace it with some char that does not for sure appear in the text... no?

Comment: nope, just use a space and plan for it... well, i suppose if it's very important that one preserves the newlines then yes, you might have to choose some funky character (I prefer meta-chars which I am sure do not exist in the text file, or triple @signs or triple pipes)

Comment: I think awk would be the answer here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw awk tag. so I add an awk one-liner, which could sovle your problem: (see test below)

```
kent$  cat a.txt
abc
@abc
@def
333
@asd
@poi
@789

kent$  awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}
        {if(c==$1){l=$0;next;} if(c) print l;c=$1;l=$0;} 
        END{print }' a.txt 
abc
@def
333
@789
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use tr with sed:

```
cat input_file | tr '\n' ' ' | sed s/<pattern>//
```

tr replaces newlines with spaces, making the regex easier.

This pattern seems to work:

```
cat file.txt | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e "s/\(@\w*\s\)*\(@\w*\s\)/\2/g"
```

Comment: You may need to tweak that a little, but it worked fine with the input you gave. I'll leave the testing and potential debugging to you :)

Comment: +1 ;) but in case original can contain spaces, you will need to come up with some other character unique enough to be separator (and regex will also change then)

Comment: indeed, you could use ``tr '\n' '#'`` or something iff you know of some char that won't be in your text file. Or, if you know there are no spaces in the source, just change the spaces back to newlines. +1 for poncha anyhow

Answer (score 1):

A multi-line `sed` solution:

```sed
sed -n '
  $p         # Always print last line
  N          # Append next line to pattern space
  /@.*\n@/D  # Delete first line of pattern space if both
             # lines start with an @, and start over
  P          # Otherwise print first line of pattern space,
  D          # delete it and start over
  ' infile
```

Comment: one thing -- if there are two blank lines between the @-words I think this will fail. Adding an asterisk to the "\n" should do the trick though, right? Interesting options passed to `sed` though!

Comment: Or `\+` rather. Yes it's a nice challenge to solve these sort of problems in `sed`. The info page is quite informative.

Answer (score 0):

http://ideone.com/Ng7p2

```
/^@/ { last_line=$0; line_to_print=true }
/^[^@]/ { if ( line_to_print == true ) print last_line; print $0; line_to_print=false }
END { if ( line_to_print == true ) print last_line }
```